# How to clean up ActiveStorage record and storage folder of development environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

According to Rails (<strike>edge</strike>`6.0`) guides, we can do *maintenance work* for ActiveStorage used in [System Test](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_storage_overview.html#discarding-files-stored-during-system-tests) and [Integration Test](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_storage_overview.html#discarding-files-stored-during-integration-tests) by calling the following statement respectively

```rb
  # System Test
  FileUtils.rm_rf("#{Rails.root}/storage_test")

  # Integration Test
  FileUtils.rm_rf(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'storage'))
```

I want to know -

Are there any Rails built-in functions or rake commands or gems to do the following?

1. remove the orphan blobs (`ActiveStorage::Blob` records those are no longer associated with any `ActiveStorage::Attachment` record)
2. remove the orphan files (files those are no longer associated with any `ActiveStorage::Blob` record)

I do not see any relevant rake tasks with `rails --tasks`.

Currently, I am using

```rb
# remove blob not associated with any attachment
ActiveStorage::Blob.where.not(id: ActiveStorage::Attachment.select(:blob_id)).find_each do |blob|
  blob.purge # or purge_later
end
```

and this script to clean orphan files (via `rails console`)

```
# run these ruby statement in project rails console
# to remove the orphan file
include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

dry_run = true
files = Dir['storage/??/??/*']

orphan = files.select do |f|
  !ActiveStorage::Blob.exists?(key: File.basename(f))
end

sum = 0
orphan.each do |f|
  sum += File.size(f)
  FileUtils.remove(f) unless dry_run
end

puts "Size: #{number_to_human_size(sum)}"
```

Comment: Looks like you got it right. I was wondering the same and looking around I didn't see anything that does it out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is a easier way now, not sure when it changed, but there is one caveat (it leaves the empty folder):

```rb
# rails < 6.1
ActiveStorage::Blob.left_joins(:attachments).where(active_storage_attachments: { id: nil }).find_each(&:purge)

# rails >= 6.1
ActiveStorage::Blob.missing(:attachments).find_each(&:purge)
```

This will delete the record in the database and delete the physical file on disk, but leave the folders the file existed in.

Comment: I didn't know [purge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-purge) is available since `v5.2.3`.

Comment: Although I am not sure there is a chance of getting orphan files (No. 2 in the question), these statements will only tackle the No. 1 in the question.

Comment: Yeah if you have files with no blob I would say you are out of luck, you'd have to use ruby to traverse every folder and check if the key exists in the db before removing, the filename is a hash that matches the `blob.key`. However this would be a expensive task on the disk if you have a ton of files already stored.

Comment: [edge guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#purging-unattached-uploads) suggests `ActiveStorage::Blob.unattached.find_each(&:purge_later)`. The `unattached` scope is available since `v5.2.3`

Comment: The `unattached` is just a scope that does the same as above, but yeah that's much nicer syntax for a `left_joins` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb#L49. The `purge_later` is also probably the correct way to go for performance unless you're already in a job or background task, although even then offloading it to a separate job might free up some memory.

Answer (score 10):

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.unattached.each(&:purge_later)
```

or just `purge` if you don't want it to happen in the background.

Comment: This seems like the best answer. My only suggestion would be to use `find_each` instead of `each` if the number of unattached blobs may be large.

Answer (score 3):

I think the @Tun suggested solution in the question itself works properly. I write it in a Rake Tasks version in case this saves sometime to the next person coming here:

```
# Usage:
#   - rake "remove_orphan_blobs"
#   - rake "remove_orphan_blobs[false]"
desc "Remove blobs not associated with any attachment"
task :remove_orphan_blobs, [:dry_run] => :environment do |_t, args|
  dry_run = true unless args.dry_run == "false"

  puts("[#{Time.now}] Running remove_orphan_blobs :: INI#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}")

  ActiveStorage::Blob.where.not(id: ActiveStorage::Attachment.select(:blob_id)).find_each do |blob|
    puts("Deleting Blob: #{ActiveStorage::Blob.service.path_for(blob.key)}#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}")
    blob.purge unless dry_run
  end

  puts("[#{Time.now}] Running remove_orphan_blobs :: END#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}")
end

# Usage:
#   - rake "remove_orphan_files"
#   - rake "remove_orphan_files[false]"
desc "Remove files not associated with any blob"
task :remove_orphan_files, [:dry_run] => :environment do |_t, args|
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  dry_run = true unless args.dry_run == "false"

  puts("[#{Time.now}] Running remove_orphan_files :: INI#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}")

  files = Dir["storage/??/??/*"]
  orphan_files = files.select do |file|
    !ActiveStorage::Blob.exists?(key: File.basename(file))
  end

  sum = 0
  orphan_files.each do |file|
    puts("Deleting File: #{file}#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}")
    sum += File.size(file)
    FileUtils.remove(file) unless dry_run
  end

  puts "Size Liberated: #{number_to_human_size(sum)}#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}"

  puts("[#{Time.now}] Running remove_orphan_files :: END#{" (dry_run activated)" if dry_run}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Work in rails 7.1.3:

ActiveStorage::Blob.unattached.each(&:purge)